# Updating multiple state variables in React using hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am using multiple state variables in a React function component and wish to update both the states (namely columns and rows for a table). I am using the `useState` hook for maintaining the states. Will using `setColumns` and `setRows` (the setters of the 2 states) on consecutive lines work for me ?
Because once the first state would be updated, the whole component will get re-rendered, so how will the next state be updated then? I am very skeptical about this.

If this won't work, what is the workaround for this ? Pls help.

**UPD**: Clarifying the question a bit more. I have a table for which I am maintaining 2 states (one for columns and one for the data (rows)). Now, in some function, I wish to update the state of both columns and rows. Since we don't have the luxury of doing it at once like in `setState` in a class component, I plan to do the updates on consecutive lines. But since each update would lead to a re-render, I am not sure if the 2nd state update would work.

Comment: Enqueued state updates from a render cycle are asynchronously batch processed. The component doesn't rerender until all enqueued updates are processed. If enqueueing multiple updates to the same state, if any subsequent update *depends* on any *previous* state then use a [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). Do you have a specific issue or a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for something you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got your question, but using 2 setters in consecutive lines will work fine. Each setter will set the new value of the variable for the next rendering.

In case your second setter depends on the first, you will need to use an `useEffect()` hooks to handle your setter.

See this example
https://dev.to/shareef/react-usestate-hook-is-asynchronous-1hia

Answer (score 1):

Before React 18, multiple state updates were batched. If you set multiple set states, it will only re-render one time. Except for promises, settimeout like async operations. If you set multiple states in a setTimeout, it will re-render multiple times.

After React 18, every multiple state update will be batched. Even it is in promises, settimeout, etc. like async operations.

For further information search: "react batch update"